# Borel set using $[a,a+1)$

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

I have the following (simple) homework:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be $\{[a,a+1)|a \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})}$

My idea was show that a borel set [a,b) is:

$[a,b)=$($\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} [a+n,a+n+1)$ ) $ 
\bigcap$ ($(\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} [b+n,b+n+1))^c$ )

But can I choose to show $[a,\infty)$ instead or is it the correct approach, input would be appreciated

Comment: What is your definition of a Borel set? I believe some books actually define Borel sets as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all such half-closed intervals (maybe even just those with rational number endpoints). Others define the collection of Borel sets as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the closed sets, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the compact sets, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing open intervals, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all intervals, etc. Then there are iterative constructions . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument shows that each $[a,b)$ is contained in $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$.
Now, you can prove that each $(a,b)$ is contained in $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$, since $(a,b) = \cup_{n} [a + \frac{1}{n} , b)$.

To solve your problem directly, you need to prove that each open set is in $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$. Then $\sigma(\mathcal{F}) \supseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, since the Borel sigma-algebra is generated by every open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Hint: each open set is a countable union of open intervals.